# A form that, when is filled out, goes into a ListView on another page in React Native?

Tags: forms, listview, react-native

Hope all is well.

I'm trying to solve a problem. Working in React Native, I have built a navigation between two screens. Now, I'd like one of them to look like a form, where I can put in some text, that will be transfered into a ListView when saved. 
& then when the task later is pressed in the ListView it goes back into 'edit-mode' in the form so one can change it again.

How is this done, does anyone know?  [This is how I want it to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCRcy.png)

I haven'd found anything on this. Not on here & not anything clear elsewhere either.

I've hardcoded most of it, however its not there yet, still working-progress. But I'm guessing this isn't the way to do it, so I'm asking if anyone can help me?

My code for the 'form':

[

import React, { Component } from 'react'

import { View, Text, Button, ListView, StyleSheet, Slider, TouchableHighlight, TouchableOpacity, TextInput } from 'react-native'

export default class HomeScreen extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }

```
static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Guest information'
}

render() {
    console.log('Home Screen!')
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation
    return (
        <View style={styles.container1}>
            <Text style={styles.text}>ANTAL PERSONER</Text>
            <Slider style={styles.slider1} />
            <Text style={styles.text2}>GUEST</Text>
            <Text style={styles.text4}>Marvin Wright</Text>
            <Text style={styles.text2}>PHONE NUMBER</Text>
            <Text style={styles.text1}>070-734 56 76</Text>
            <Text style={styles.text2}>ESTIMATED WAITING TIME</Text>
            <Slider style={styles.slider} />
            <TextInput style={styles.text3}
              placeholder=' Comment'></TextInput>
              <View style={styles.container}>
            <TouchableHighlight
              underlayColor="#0a9911"
              style={styles.button1}
                onPress={() => navigate('Booking')}
                // title="SAVE"
                // color="purple"
              >
                <Text style={styles.textColor}>Delete</Text>
              </TouchableHighlight>

              <TouchableOpacity
                style={styles.button}
                  onPress={() => navigate('Booking')}
                  // title="DELETE"
                  // color="red"
                >
                  <Text style={styles.textColor}>Save</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
        </View>
    )
}
```

}

```
  const styles = StyleSheet.create({

  text: {
    marginTop: 50,
    marginLeft: 55,
    fontSize: 10,
    color: 'grey'
  },

  text1: {
    marginTop: 5,
    marginLeft: 55,
    fontSize: 20
  },

  text2: {
    marginTop: 35,
    marginLeft: 55,
    fontSize: 10,
    color: 'grey'
  },

  text3: {
    marginTop: 20,
    marginLeft: 55,
    marginRight: 55,
    marginBottom: 60,
    fontSize: 15,
    borderRadius: 2,
    borderColor: 'white',
    borderStyle: 'solid',
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderBottomWidth: 70,
    borderTopWidth: 5,
    color: 'grey',
  },

  text4: {
    marginTop: 5,
    marginLeft: 55,
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: 'bold'
  },

  slider: {
    marginTop: 10,
    marginLeft: 55,
    marginRight: 55,
    marginBottom: 5,
    backgroundColor: 'white'
  },

  slider1: {
    marginTop: 10,
    marginLeft: 55,
    marginRight: 55,
    backgroundColor: 'white'
  },

  button: {
    backgroundColor: '#5f316b',
    width: '44%',
    height: 45,
    borderRadius: 7
  },

  button1: {
    backgroundColor: '#e53a24',
    width: '44%',
    height: 45,
    borderRadius: 7
  },

  textColor: {
    color: 'white',
    alignSelf: 'center',
    paddingTop: 12.5,
    fontSize: 17
  },

  container1: {
    flex: 1,
    // flexDirection: 'solid',
    // justifyContent: 'space',
    backgroundColor: 'white'
  },

container: {
  // flex: 1,
  flexDirection: 'row',
  justifyContent: 'space-around',
}
```

});
]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few options:

You can pass and update the data in a parent component to the views, which is known as having a higher order component. This is a technique where you store the data in the parent and pass them in the child components through props along with functions to update the parent state/props. https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html

Or, you can use a data store such as `react-redux`, `mobx-react` or other datastore libraries, which are basically high order components themselves that specialize in passing data through components.